# Derived class override ApplicationDidEnterForeground invocation in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a BaseViewController with a default method of ApplicationDidEnterForeground(). The ContactController is derived from BaseViewController, and i want to invoke another method from ContactController inside its own definition of ApplicationDidEnterForeground().

So right now i have:
BaseViewController.ApplicationDidEnterForeground() as a

```
public virtual void ApplicationDidEnterForeground{

//What do i put here to invoke derived class

}
```

ContactController.ApplicationDidEnterForeground() is an override void

in ContactController

```
public override void ApplicationDidEnterForeground()
    {
    base.ApplicationDidEnterForeground();
    ReloadTableView();

    }
```

Right now with my iOS device i set breakpoints at both methods. However only the BaseViewController is invoked and i can't use ReloadTableView() when my application goes to background to foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**  Different from Android , in iOS , the life cycle **UIViewController** doesn't have such a method like `ApplicationDidEnterForeground` . So when the app goes to background to foreground the method will never been invoked .

**Solution:**

The life cycle of the whole app is in `AppDelegate` and  `SceneDelegate`(after iOS 13.0) .

You need to push notification in the relevant method and handle it in your ViewController .

#### in Appdelegate

```
 [Export("applicationWillEnterForeground:")]
 public void AppWillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
 {
     NSNotification notification = NSNotification.FromName("WillEnterForeground", null);

     NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification(notification);
 }
```

#### in SceneDelegate (if have)

```
[Export ("sceneWillEnterForeground:")]
public void WillEnterForeground (UIScene scene)
{

    NSNotification notification = NSNotification.FromName("WillEnterForeground", null);

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification(notification);

}
```

And in your ViewController

```
   public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("WillEnterForeground"),(notify)=> {

            // refresh table here

        });
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(this, "WillEnterForeground", null);

    }
```

You need to register the notification in each ViewController so that You can handle the different logic .